# Is there a way for a process to know that dtrace has attached?

Tags: c, macos, profiling, dtrace

I introduced an environment option which pauses my process at startup so that I can attach dtrace (by way of XCode Instruments) and start profiling.  I then have to press enter on the process to start it running.  I'm wondering if there is a way for my process to know that dtrace has been attached so that it can immediately start running as soon as the profiler attaches rather than having to wait for user input.  Is there a signal or memory value that gets set in the process when dtrace attaches?

Comment: Only a signal that restarts the process could possibly do this. Setting a memory value wouldn't help, since the process can't check the memory if it's not running. And as far as I know, there's no such signal.

Comment: The process is actually running, it's just waiting on input from stdin, but it could easily check something while "waiting".

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of situations where this is useful, so DTrace has the capability to run the process itself to force tracing to start immediately using the `-c` option:

```
   -c     Run  the  specified  command cmd and exit upon its completion.
          If more than one -c option is present on the command line, dtrace
          exits when all commands have exited, reporting the exit status for
          each child process as it terminates. The process-ID of the first
          command is made available to any D programs specified on the command
          line or using the -s option through the $target macro variable.
```

Inside the D script, you can use `$target` to refer to the process you started with `-c`, like in the probe name `pid$target::malloc:entry` or the condition `/pid == $target/`.

In case that doesn't work for some reason, the exact mechanism you're asking for isn't super easy to do, because DTrace mostly doesn't allow side-effects that are visible to the process being traced. Getting creative, I suppose instead of waiting for input on `stdin`, you could check what time it is in a loop, and in the DTrace script you could use the [destructive action](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-actsub-4/index.html) `void chill(int nanoseconds)` to pause your program in the `BEGIN` block for a second or so. Then your program could detect the pause due to >1s passing since the most recent clock measurement, and start running.

Comment: That would work great but I'm doing the profiling with the XCode Instruments app.

Comment: @ViperBailey What about the chill() method I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way since you're writing the program and dtrace is designed to be non-intrusive would be to create a file to use as a flag.  You can either have the program create it or only create it manually when you want to do debugging.  Then you have the program start and look for what file, if it exists then it paused and watches the file.  When the file is removed it will continue, then you can have your dtrace script or maybe a secondary script started at the same time remove the file.   When you don't want to debug, you just don't create the file.  When you do you create the file and have the debugging remove the file as part of their start up.

Comment: Can you please show some code or prototyping as an example?